# Проблема возвращения ссылки на массив в C#

Tags: c#, list

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как корректно передавать ссылку на массив (например список) из класса в класс. Например: есть список в `Class1`, неважно чего, например объектов некого класса3. Мне нужно использовать и редактировать его в `Class2`.

Ниже примеры, как пытаюсь делать - передаю через методы или через public `IEnumerable`. Как правильно?

1.

```
class Class1
{
    private List<Class3> _list  = new List<Class3>(5);
    // .....
    public IEnumerable<Class3> GetList()
    {
        return _list.AsEnumerable(); 
    }
}
```

2. 

```
class Class1
{
    private List<Class3> _list  = new List<Class3> (5);
    // .....
    public List<Class3> GetList()
    {
        return _list; 
    }
}
```

3. 

```
class Class1
{
    private List<Class3> _list  = new List<Class3> (5);
    public IEnumerable<Class3> GetList
    {
        get { return _list.AsEnumerable(); }
    }
    // .....
}
```

Comment: А почему нельзя просто `public List<Class3> { get; } = new();` ? Ну а вообще, это все зависит от задачи, которую вы нам не говорите, ибо если эта коллекция генерируется методом, то методу и возвращать (вариант 1), если это некая общая коллекция, то бессмысленно делать приватный список, чтоб потом дергать его через свойство, делайте сразу свойство и с ним работайте.

Comment: Странно ведет себя StackOverflow, в предпросмотре вопроса показывает одно, а когда сохраняешь - другое, пришлось кучу раз отредактировать, чтобы заработал этот список между блоками.

Comment: _использовать и редактировать_ - вы не сможете редактировать IEnumerable, только перечислять. Вот и отталкивайтесь от того, что нужно делать: только перечислять - `IEnumerable`, добавлять/удалять элементы - `ICollection`, обращаться по индексу - `IList` и т. п.

Comment: Про первый пример кода с ответом в комментарии @AlexanderPetrov абсолютно согласен, вернув IEnumerable вы не сможете обращаться к элементам по индексу, если это вам не нужно, то это наиболее предпочтительный общий способ работы с коллекциями - клиентскому коду не надо задумываться как совершать обход коллекции, всё делается единообразно и для массивов и для списков и для словарей и ещё много чего.

Comment: Ещё хотелось бы подчеркнуть разницу между 1 и 3 примером. В первом вы используете доступ через метод, в 3 через свойство. Есть такое правило: если стоимость доступа условно "бесплатна", то используй свойство, это удобно. Если при доступе производятся некоторые, опять же условно "затратные" вычисления, то используй метод. Это наведёт других разработчиков на мысль, что при интенсивном использовании этого метода можно, например, закешировать возвращаемый им результат, чтобы каждый раз не производились эти вычисления.

Comment: Удалось разобраться? Был ли ответ полезен? Если да, отметьте ответ принятым.

Answer (score 1):

Через конструктор

```cs
class Class1
{
    private List<Class3> _list = new List<Class3>();

    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        Class2 class2 = new Class2(_list);
    }
}

class Class2
{
    private List<Class3> _list;

    public Class2(List<Class3> list)
    {
        _list = list;
    }
}
```

Через поле или свойство, покажу свойство

```cs
class Class1
{
    private List<Class3> _list = new List<Class3>();

    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        Class2 class2 = new Class2();
        class2.List = _list;
        // или так
        // Class2 class2 = new Class2() { List = _list };
    }
}

class Class2
{
    public List<Class3> List { get; set; }
}
```

Конечно, вы таким образом не сможете переприсвоить `_list` внутри `Class1` из какого-то метода `Class2`, но элементы изменять сможете.

Если вам надо вернуть новый список из `Class2` в `Class1`, можно использовать возвращаемое значение у метода.

```cs
class Class1
{
    private List<Class3> _list;

    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        Class2 class2 = new Class2();
        _list = class2.SomeMethod2();
    }
}

class Class2
{
    public List<Class3> SomeMethod2()
    {
        List<Class3> list = new List<Class3>();
        //...
        return list;
    }
}
```